# How to save webpage with css and js files from C# webbrowser?

Tags: c#, jquery, web-crawler

I tried to save rendered C# web browser to my hdd. But it only save html source only, no css or jquery js file. I tried with 3 methods.

1. It only creates only html file without any css, and jquery js files.
   File.WriteAllText(myDocumentPath, webBrowser5.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml, Encoding.GetEncoding(webBrowser5.Document.Encoding));

2.It only creates content text. No html, css, js
File.WriteAllText(@"text.txt", webBrowser5.Document.Body.InnerText);

3.It creates bigger html file, still no css or jquery js files
writer.Write(webBrowser5.DocumentText);

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String source = ("viewsource.html");
        StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(source);
        String myDocumentPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\111.html";

        //It only creates only html file without any css, and jquery js files.
        File.WriteAllText(myDocumentPath, webBrowser5.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml, Encoding.GetEncoding(webBrowser5.Document.Encoding));

        //it only creates content text
        File.WriteAllText(@"text.txt", webBrowser5.Document.Body.InnerText);

        //It creates bigger html file, still no css or jquery js files
        writer.Write(webBrowser5.DocumentText);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution on codeproject. MHTML is the way to go.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12977/Harvesting-Web-Content-into-MHTML-Archive

Other solution is save as image:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6601/Capture-an-HTML-document-as-an-image